# Let $a_1=1$ and $a_{n+1} =\frac{a_n}{a_n+2}$ for all $n$ greater than or equal to $1$. Prove that the sequence is decreasing and find its limit.

Tags: sequences-and-series

I can see that the sequence is monotonically decreasing and bounded converges to a limit. But I do not understand why the solutions say that this sequence converges to a limit which satisfies $a=\frac{a}{a+2}$ (by passing to the limit in the identity $a_{n+1}$) ?

Comment: Do we know what $a_2$ is, or could it be whatever it likes? And do you mean $a = \frac aa + 2$ or $a = \frac a{a+2}$ in the last line? Perhaps the recursuion should've been $a_{n+1} = \frac{a_n}{a_n + 2}$ instead? These misunderstandings are why you _must_ be precice when writing mathematics on a computer. See [this guide](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for some pointers on how it's best done on this site.

Comment: a_2 is 1/3. Also it is a=a/(a+2)

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, observe that $\boxed{a_n\in [0, 1]}$ for every $n$, which can be proved by induction principle.

(Since $a_1\in [0,1]$, induction base holds. Assumption $a_n\in [0,1]$ implies $0 \leq a_{n+1}=\frac{a_n}{a_n+2}<1$, so induction step holds.)

Secondly, $\boxed{\text{$a_n$ is decreasing}}$ by induction principle:

Induction base holds $a_2<a_1$.

For induction step assume that $a_{n-1}\geq a_{n}$. Function $f(x)=\frac{x}{x+2}$ is increasing (since $f'(x)=\frac{2}{(x+2)^2}>0$), so it preserves inequality. Therefore, $a_n=f(a_{n-1})\geq f(a_n)=a_{n+1}$.

$\boxed{\text{Monotone and bounded sequence converges.}}$

Therefore, exists $L=\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n.$
Let us compute $L$. From equality $$a_{n+1}=\frac{a_n}{a_n+2},$$ by letting $\lim_{n\to\infty}$, we have 
$$L=\frac{L}{L+2}$$ and $$L(L+1)=0.$$
We conclude $$\boxed{L=0.}$$ (Since all $a_n$ are positive, limit can not be negative,  $L\neq -1$)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that what Arthur says is correct, that the actual relation between the terms in the sequence is $$a_{n+1}=\frac{a_n}{a_n+2},$$ notice that $$\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} a_{n+1} = \lim\limits_{n\to \infty} \frac{a_n}{a_n+2}.$$ Since both the limits of numerator and denominator exist (you should prove that $a_n+2$ does not converge to $0$), we have $$\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} a_{n+1} = \lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\frac{a_n}{a_n+2} = \frac{\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}a_n}{\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}a_n+2}.$$ The rest should be obvious.

Comment: Also since by the relation $a_n \geq 0$ for any $n$, we have $a_{n+1} \leq a_n /2$ or $a_{n+1} \leq a_1 2^{-n} = 2^{-n}$, which converges to zero. Thus $a_n \to 0$ by the squeeze test.